# Z-index on header not working

Tags: html, css, z-index

I know this is asked a lot, and that z-index cannot work on items that aren't positioned. Yet, I'm clearly missing something here. The goal is to have my header cover most of the page initially, and on a click move up to reveal the body content.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  height: 95vh;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.leaf {
  height: 50px;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0px 0px 20px -25px;
}

.categories {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.chars {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Title Placeholder</h1>
  <svg class="leaf" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
            <g>
              <g>
                <path d="M219.388,46.202c-45.273,7.148-86.333,28.057-118.741,60.466l-7.059,7.059C52.895,154.42,30.486,208.523,30.486,266.07
                  c0,52.508,18.666,102.144,52.846,141.346L0,490.747L21.253,512l83.33-83.33c39.202,34.18,88.838,52.846,141.346,52.846
                  c57.548,0,111.65-22.41,152.343-63.102l7.059-7.059c32.409-32.408,53.318-73.469,60.466-118.741L512,0L219.388,46.202z
                   M436.11,287.924c-6.152,38.957-24.144,74.288-52.03,102.176l-7.059,7.059c-68.705,68.705-178.36,72.098-251.119,10.193
                  l239.44-239.439l-21.253-21.253L104.647,386.1c-61.904-72.759-58.512-182.414,10.194-251.119l7.059-7.059
                  c27.888-27.887,63.219-45.879,102.176-52.03l251.79-39.756L436.11,287.924z"/>
              </g>
            </g>
          </svg>
          </header>
          <div class="categories">
            <h2>Characteristics</h2>
            <div class="chars leaves"></div>
            <div class="chars fruit"></div>
            <div class="chars flowers"></div>
            <div class="chars twigs"></div>
            <div class="chars other"></div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or working URL to look at? What are you seeing at the moment?

Comment: Your `<svg>` doesn't have closing tag...

Comment: And your snippet doesn't show any attempt to change the header. It's just a block that happens to be positioned relatively, but in exactly the same position as it was when it wouldn't have been positioned. Did you mean `position: sticky` or something?

Comment: It's showing the "categories" div appearing inside the header. https://codepen.io/vortilad/pen/WXowpP?editors=0110

Answer (score 0):

IF I understand correctly what you want, there is no z-index issue. Everything is correctly positioned.

The only thing missing is that the header has a transparent background. Adding `background-color: white;` to the header block in the CSS makes it work.

Comment: Well, yep. That was it. I really appreciate you pointing out what should have be obvious. I'm gonna go slink back to my office in shame now.